# Add a Google Contact using the .NET API 1.6.0.0

Tags: .net, gmail, contacts, google-api

I had everything working great in 1.4.0.2 but updated to 1.6.0.0 and now I can't get the code to work for adding a contact to a Gmail account.

Does anyone have sample .NET code or a link to an example of adding (creating) a contact entry and submitting it to Google (gmail)?

Thank you.

Comment: It might be useful to post your code that doesn't work anymore as well as some details about the failure that occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an answer yet and have been away from this project for sometime, a newer API may be available by now which I'll investigate.